# jQuery two if statements for 1 variable, but only works for one

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement, return

Let me try to explain what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to make a memory puzzle, but I have a hard time with the variable, the if statements and returning.

Can you please take a look at my example and click three or four times on the blocks. I want to add some action when the variable == 1 and something else when the variable == 2.
But as you can see, this won't work because it skips alerting 1 after one time...
Is this a problem with the return()? I believe so, but I hope you can explain me how I can fix this and if it has to do with return.

**[Example JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9rrRa/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="coverup">
    <div class="hoverdiv"></div>
    <div class="image_A"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="coverup">
    <div class="hoverdiv"></div>
    <div class="image_B"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="coverup">
    <div class="hoverdiv"></div>
    <div class="image_A"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="coverup">
    <div class="hoverdiv"></div>
    <div class="image_B"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var amountofclicks = 0;

$('.coverup').bind("click", function (event) {

  if (amountofclicks < 2) {
    $(this).find('.letter').show();
    amountofclicks++;

    if (amountofclicks == 2) {
      alert('2');
    }
    if (amountofclicks == 1) {
      alert('1');
    }
    $(this).children().show();


  } else {
    $('.coverup').children().hide();
    $(this).children().show();
    amountofclicks = 1;
    return;
  }


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `ammountofclicks` to zero at the end. Also there are more ifs than it is needed. The function should run only if the tile is not already visible or `ammountofclicks` are zero, so there is one more check at the beggining.

```
var amountofclicks = 0;

$('.coverup').bind("click", function (event) {
  if (amountofclicks==0 || !$(this).children().is(":visible")) {
    amountofclicks++;
    if (amountofclicks == 1) {
      $('.coverup').children().hide();
    }
    $(this).find('.letter').show();
    $(this).children().show();
    alert(amountofclicks);
    if (amountofclicks == 2) {
      amountofclicks = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the if-clause

```
if (amountofclicks == 2) { ... }
```

could never be reached because it's inside the following if-clause

```
if (amountofclicks < 2) { ... }
```

more detailed...

```
var amountofclicks = 2;

if (amountofclicks < 2) {
    // go here if amountofclicks < 2
    if (amountofclicks == 1) {
        // go here if amountofclicks == 1
    }
    if (amountofclicks == 2) {
        // unreachable, because amountofclicks is always < 2
    }
} else {
    // go here if amountofclicks >= 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var amountofclicks = 0;

$('.coverup').bind("click", function (event) {

  if (amountofclicks <= 2) {
    $(this).find('.letter').show();


    if (amountofclicks == 2) {
      alert('2');
    }
    if (amountofclicks == 1) {
      alert('1');
    }
    amountofclicks++;
    $(this).children().show();


  } else {
    $('.coverup').children().hide();
    $(this).children().show();
    amountofclicks = 1;
    return;
  }


});
```